# Can i enhance touch sensitivity of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I am working on an app, here i have two button, which navigate through the stories in my app, say next and previous buttons. They are not tapped properly, i mean i have to tap them twice or thrice to make them work on device. Is there anyway that i can increase the sensitivity of the buttons so that the work on just one tap. Any Suggestions and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout`s, with 10-15 dp of Paddings/Margins to enclose each of the `Button`s and register the touch listener to the `RelativeLayout`s instead of the `Button`s.

Answer (score 0):

Is this different from the behavior of buttons elsewhere on your device?  If so, you have done something strange in your app that has broken things.  If not, then this is just an issue with how your device works and there is little you are likely to be to do to make the buttons in your app behave differently.

One thing you can do is put the Development (DevTools) app on your device and turn on Pointer Location to see on your screen the actual pointer events being generated.

Comment: I don't know how small your buttons are, but if you make them small enough they will certainly be hard to touch.